# Unique only cartesian product of several lists

Tags: python, list, cartesian-product

The following works well for `cart_product([1,2,3], [a,b,c], [v])`, doesn't it also return duplicate cartesian product, if so, how to get unique cartesian products?

```
import itertools
def cart_product(*somelists):
    for element in itertools.product(*somelists):
        print element
```

also this doesn't seem to work when I pass in a list containing lists `[ [1,2,3],[a,b,c],[v] ]`

Comment: this works fine for me. What do you mean by duplicate products?

Comment: it didn't work for me and I found my answer. people don't seem to thrilled about it tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get only the unique elements, you can use set notation like this (**Note:** This doesnt guarantee the order)

   ```
   return list({element for element in itertools.product(*somelists)})
   ```

   or as per Paul Draper's comment we can do it like this

   ```
   list(set(itertools.product(*somelists)))
   ```

   If you want to maintain the order as well

   ```
   import itertools
   def cart_product(somelists):
       result, tempSet = [], set()
       for element in itertools.product(*somelists):
           if element not in tempSet:
           tempSet.add(element)
           result.append(element)
       return result
   ```
2. To make your program work with list of lists, just change the function declaration from

   ```
   def cart_product(*somelists):
   ```

   to

   ```
   def cart_product(somelists):
   ```